# python .apply calling function error

Tags: python

```
def awesome_count():
    if 'awesome' in dict:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
products['awesome']= products['word_count'].apply(awesome_count)
```

TypeError: awesome_count() takes no arguments (1 given)

what is the issue with calling the function. can somebody help?

Comment: What kind of object is `products['word_count']`?

Comment: Whatever the `.apply()` method does, includes calling `awesome_count()` with one argument, but your function accepts none.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. word_count is one field name for table products.

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything. Obviously it is an object type that has a `.apply()` method, but I have no idea what that type is. We cannot help you until you can tell us more about that type.

Comment: @MartijnPieters. word_count is a dictionary type

Comment: Dictionaries don't have an `apply()` method.

Comment: {'and': 5L, 'stink': 1L,
'because': 1L, 'order ...
like this

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve], including how `products` is created, so that people trying to answer your question can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `awesome_count` function should take one argument, `dict`:

```
def awesome_count(dict):
    ....
```

You should really call it something besides `dict` though as that is a built-in data type.  For something simple like this `d` would be fine.

Another thing to keep in mind is that `Python` is not `javascript` -- there is no `apply` method on `dict`s unless you have subclassed and added it yourself.